# Google search on domain name shows hostname

Tags: google, domains, redirects

A small organistion changed its name, registered the corresponding new domain name and set website forwarding to the old domain name. This was done through setting "Masked Redirect" via the hosting Control Panel. Both sites are hosted by the same hosting company.

Because the website code is actually on the old domain, Google search gets to the website But also reveals the old domain name.

They need to keep access to the domain control panel for the website separate from the domain control panel for the email accounts for control purposes.

Can this be achieved by just altering some control records ? Using Google tools or something else ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the masked redirect.   Masked redirects are not good for SEO.   They work by using a frameset on the domain to completely contain another domain:

```
<frameset rows="100%">
  <frameset cols="100%">
    <frame src="http://example.com/page.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
  </frameset>
</frameset>
```

There is no actual content on the domain for Google to index.   All the content is on the framed domain.   When you used control panel masked redirects, you usually only have the option of specifying the redirect URL.   There is not usually even an opportunity to set the page title.  Google doesn't have anything to show except for the hostname.

If you want to correct this problem you will have to use something other than masked redirects.